# DSS framework and PDFBox migrate signed digest to PDF

Tags: java, hash, pdfbox, digital-signature, signature

Let's say we have a PDF. Through the DSS framework we get the digest. Then we send it to a provider lets say Adacom which signs the digest and returns a *.pkcs7 file. How can someone embed this file inside the pdf document?

Comment: Maybe this helps   https://github.com/crs2195/signature

Comment: It is very strange... Although it says PDFBox, it uses iText... https://github.com/crs2195/signature/blob/master/RemoteSignature-%20PDFBox/CSC-PDFBox/src/main/java/CSCPAdESSignature.java

Comment: Weird. But CSCSignature.java uses PDFBox.

Comment: You do not only need a hash value from preparations, you also need the prepared pdf to inject the resulting p#7 into, either as a complete file or as a recipe how exactly to prepare from the original pdf.

Comment: Yes but how is that done? Is there any example?

Comment: There are the Create*Signature*.java examples in the source code download. What's missing is to get that external stuff into the format needed in the PDF, i.e. you need to convert this pkcs7 file into hex and then into the PDF (assuming this pkcs7 file is really the correct format)

Comment: *"Through the DSS framework we get the digest."* - What exactly do you mean here? Do you mean the digital signature related examples (`CreateSignature` and friends) of PDFBox? Or do you mean the CEF Digital [eSignature DSS](https://github.com/esig/dss)  code? Or yet something else?

Comment: The 2nd one. eSignature DSS. By just adding the hex as a digest to the document, the result wil be a signed doc?